# What is wrong with my java code/function?

Tags: java

I am trying to count the number of words in a sentence that contain exactly two vowels between a pair of “z” characters with no "z" between them. There may be multiple spaces between words, and a letter may be upper or lower case. Show the number of words in each sentence that match the pattern. Keep reading sentences until the user enters "*". What is wrong with my current code. I have two classes In and Root, In being for output/input.
I have the following code for root which has many problems;
//

```
public class Root
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   new Root();  }

    public Root()
    {  
        String sentence = readSentence();
        int count = 0;

        while(!(sentence = readSentence()).equals("*"))
        {
            System.out.println("  Matching words = " + words(sentence));

        }


    }

    private int words(String sentence)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(String word: sentence.split(" +"))
        {
            if(matches(word))
                count++;
        }

        return count;
    }

    private boolean matches(String word)
    {
        int Vowels = 3;
        for( int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = word.charAt(i);

            if( c == 'z')
            {
                for (i=3; i<word.length(); ++i) {
                    if (word.charAt(i)=='z' && word.charAt(i-3)=='z' && isVowel(word.charAt(i-1)) && isVowel(word.charAt(i-2))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            else if(isVowel(c))
            {

            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isVowel(char c)
    {
        return "aeiou".contains("" + c);

    }

    private String readSentence()
    {
        //prompt
        System.out.println("Sentence: *");
        //return Value

        return In.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

Comment: You must say what problem you are facing. Compile/Runtime Errors,wrong output

Answer (score 0):

Your `matches` method has an inner loop that uses the same index - `i` - as the outer loop. This can't be right. Use a different variable for the inner loop.

In addition, your `Root` constructor does nothing with the sentence returned by the first call to `readSentence()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some recommendations.

- You should use `indexOf` method instead of `contains` as you can pass directly a char.
- You should declare the `aeiou` value in a constant to avoid re-creating it each time the method is called.
- Variables by convention must start with a lower case letter and a capital letter for each subsequent words.
- You use the same variable `i` in your inner loop which is probably the main cause of your problem.